# Google Maps Api error al querer exportar la referencia del mapa

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-maps

Tengo una pagina en la que quiero incluir la api de google maps, ya tengo el script conectado a mi pagina, pero tengo un problema. Necesito poder exportar el resultado del initMap (funcion la cual pide inicializar en el script la api de google maps) y no puedo hacerlo porque me da errores, tengo 2 archivos js:
inicializar.js:

```
export function initMap() {
    return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 11,
        center: { lat: 40.23238925881008, lng: -100.70052936550995 }
    });
}
```

codigo.js:

```
import { initMap } from "./inicializar.js"
const mapita = initMap();

console.log(mapita);
```

y el html en donde estan estos scripts mas el de la api:

```
<script src="/build/js/codigo.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="/build/js/inicializar.js"></script>

<script async
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${key}&libraries=places,geometry&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

El mapa se muestra pero en la consola me aparece esto, deberia darle importancia? o como podria solucionar este error en la consola?:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías probar no importando `inicializar` desde el index.  Lo importante es que  `codigo.js` se cargue como módulo y él pueda leer sus dependencias. El resto es música.

Comment: incluye el html